# show data in Listbox c# from sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this code to show data from SQL to listbox in c#

```
public DataTable get_mada_listbox()
    {
        DAL.DATAACSESSLAYER dal = new DAL.DATAACSESSLAYER();

        dal.open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = dal.selectData("get_mada_listbox", null);
        dal.close();
        return dt;


    }
```

When I call the function:

```
BL.cls_product prd = new BL.cls_product();


        listBox1.DataSource = prd.get_mada_listbox();
```

The listbox should show 
`system.data.data row view`.

## How can I solve it?

i solve my problem by add 
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "mada_name";

next this 
            listBox1.DataSource = prd.get_mada_listbox();

thx

Comment: You should learn about DisplayMember and DataMember properties of ListBox

Comment: You can help me the way

Comment: read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: sory but i am beginner can u edit my code ,thx

Comment: if you solved it, add it as an _Answer_, don't modify the _question_

Comment: Go for it and you will be able to do it: https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be your method:

```
void get_mada_listbox()
    {
        var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection connsql = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            connsql.Open();

            // Sql Adapter
            using (SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM DataTable", connection))
            {            
                // fill a data table
                var data_table = new DataTable();
                sqlAdapter.Fill(t);

                // Bind the table to the list box
                listBox1.DisplayMember = "mada_name";
                listBox1.ValueMember = "mada_value";
                listBox1.DataSource = data_table;
            }
        }
    }
```